# iOS Black screen while loading from xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I am trying to load application with .xib file. I don't know why my screen turns black...

My AppDelegate code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    MainViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is `self.window == nil`?

Comment: Do I need to initialize it? If so, how to do it?

Comment: Yeah, `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];` Adding as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build your application manually (not using a storyboard), you need to create your own window.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

When using Storyboards, the application does this whole process before calling `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. That's why UIApplicationDelegate.window was added in iOS 5 and many modern tutorials don't show you the setup steps.  Before then it was just common practice to have that property.